# Display unordered list inline on mobile and desktop. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, html, css, html-lists

My current coding displays the `<ul>` inline on desktop but not mobile. Also, how do I make the `<p>` section inline with the `<ul>`?

I tried the following code. I added the `.div-Cuisine` to prevent the styling from affecting the rest of the page. I thought IT WORKED, then I checked mobile and saw that the inline formatting is not reflected. and the list delivers one bullet per line. What should I do?

```
<style>
.div-Cuisine{
ul li{
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
}
p, ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
}
</style>
<div class="div-Cuisine"><?php
 
//Display a list of all the categories of custom post types
 
$terms = get_terms(
         array(
                'post_type'   => 'recipe',
                'taxonomy'   => 'cuisine', // Custom Post Type Taxonomy Slug
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'order'         => 'asc'
            )
         );
 
echo '<p>Recipe Cuisines: </p><ul>';

echo '<ul>'; 

foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>, </li> ';
    }
 
echo '</ul>';
 
?>
<?php
 
//Display a list of all the categories of custom post types
 
$terms = get_terms(
         array(
                'post_type'   => 'recipe',
                'taxonomy'   => 'recipe_type', // Custom Post Type Taxonomy Slug
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'order'         => 'asc'
            )
         );
 
echo '<p>Recipe Types: </p>';
 
echo '<ul>';
 
foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term).'">'.$term->name.'</a>, </li> ';
    }
 
echo '</ul>';
 
?>
</div>
```

Currently the mobile view is a long list with bullets. The desktop view would be perfect if the

section was inline with the 
Desktop view:
[image: desktop view]

Comment: that depends on the css of the template. the trick is to use dev tools on mobile view and find the culprit css rule for the list, and override it. btw, your css has syntax error because it's nested and that is not supported.

Comment: I don't see how the PHP is relevant here. Post a [mcve] with your rendered HTML and CSS please

Comment: @ITgoldman: Thank you for your response. Is it possible to make the inline CSS apply to the recipe types and cuisines without nesting it? It worked on mobile and desktop until I nested it, but I thought I had to nest it so that the rest of the page appears properly. It seems that either the page functions right or the mobile view works...but not both. At least for now.

Comment: @j08691 : I tagged php because I thought that was the only way to list the recipe types and cuisines. Do you know of a better way? Thanks for your response!

Comment: @ITgoldman nesting in CSS is supported in main browsers now though & may be required.

Comment: @JerryChristensen Using PHP to make your list is fine, but we need to see what the PHP is generating. Again, see [mcve] please

Comment: in css3 it wasn't supprted. anyway you can easily flatten it, like `.div-Cuisine ul li { ... }`.  as a last ditch if it works on desktop view, try to add `!important` to the css rules

Comment: _"Also, how do I make the <p> section inline with the <ul>?"_ - by taking `float` out of there, I would think, because that seems counter-productive to what you actually want. Paragraphs, lists and list items should all be inline here. Add a wrapper div around the p and ul, so that they don't _all_ come one after the other, but you still have that separation of "sections".